# How can I merge two arrays of objects together when one array is 2D?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two accounts that I am trying to merge and created a recursive function to merge...

```
const primaryAccount = [
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    },
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      disclosures: {
        employment_status: 'EMPLOYED',
        employer_name: '',
        employer_address: '',
        employment_position: '',
        is_control_person: false,
        is_affiliated_exchange_or_finra: false,
        is_politically_exposed: false,
        immediate_family_exposed: false,
        is_discretionary: false
      },
      agreements: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [ 'us_equity', 'crypto' ]
    }
  ]


const subAccounts = [
    [
     {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    },
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      disclosures: {
        employment_status: 'EMPLOYED',
        employer_name: '',
        employer_address: '',
        employment_position: '',
        is_control_person: false,
        is_affiliated_exchange_or_finra: false,
        is_politically_exposed: false,
        immediate_family_exposed: false,
        is_discretionary: false
      },
      agreements: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [ 'us_equity', 'crypto' ]
    }
    ],
    [
     {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    },
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      disclosures: {
        employment_status: 'EMPLOYED',
        employer_name: '',
        employer_address: '',
        employment_position: '',
        is_control_person: false,
        is_affiliated_exchange_or_finra: false,
        is_politically_exposed: false,
        immediate_family_exposed: false,
        is_discretionary: false
      },
      agreements: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [ 'us_equity', 'crypto' ]
    }
    ]
]
```

```
let accounts = [];

const mergeAccounts = (arr) => {
  if(arr[0].constructor === Array) {
    arr.forEach((a, index) => {
      mergeAccounts(a)
    })
  }
  // get first index which is the trading account
  const tradingAccount = arr.shift();

  accounts.push({
    accountInfo: arr[0],
    tradingAccount
  });
}

mergeAccounts(primaryAccount)
mergeAccounts(subAccounts)
```

I get the desired outcome but there is a fourth index that I am unsure how it is getting populated. The desired outcome is to have 3 in my array.

outcome:

```
accounts:  [
  {
    accountInfo: {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      contact: [Object],
      identity: [Object],
      disclosures: [Object],
      agreements: [Array],
      trusted_contact: [Object],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      minor_identity: [Object],
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [Array]
    },
    tradingAccount: {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    }
  },
  {
    accountInfo: {
      id: '690716e2-3561-4e8c-a207-b7260e485805',
      account_number: '794718269',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:39:41.475802Z',
      contact: [Object],
      identity: [Object],
      disclosures: [Object],
      agreements: [Array],
      trusted_contact: [Object],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      minor_identity: [Object],
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [Array]
    },
    tradingAccount: {
      id: '690716e2-3561-4e8c-a207-b7260e485805',
      account_number: '794718269',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:39:41.475802Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    }
  },
  {
    accountInfo: {
      id: '36fce4e8-3df9-4252-91dc-08bb5232aeec',
      account_number: '794431295',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:40:25.438666Z',
      contact: [Object],
      identity: [Object],
      disclosures: [Object],
      agreements: [Array],
      trusted_contact: [Object],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      minor_identity: [Object],
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [Array]
    },
    tradingAccount: {
      id: '36fce4e8-3df9-4252-91dc-08bb5232aeec',
      account_number: '794431295',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:40:25.438666Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    }
  },
  { accountInfo: [ [Object] ], tradingAccount: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

What am I missing where the extra
`{ accountInfo: [ [Object] ], tradingAccount: [ [Object] ] }`
is being added at the end?

Comment: Could you provide an example? Array.concat just flattens my subAccounts array

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: No worries, the ask is pretty simple though, not custom work...
How do I turn 
`[{}] + [[{}, {}], [{},{}]] = [{key1: {}, key1: {}}, {key1: {}, key1: {}}, {key1: {}, key1: {}}];`

Comment: update your question, don't use comments for that. + simply fy your question to essential information synthesis with relevant values => don't have hundred properties,   don't use `[Object]` as value,

Comment: Can you share an exemple (with values) for `primaryAccount ` and `subAccounts`, so we can't try update your function to get the desired output ;)

Comment: @nem0z here is a repl that I've been using to test
https://replit.com/join/rzzskmsdph-cmcglynn-nesteg

Answer (score 0):

You can create new array, decompose your first array and map over your second array and insert the first element.

```js
const primaryAccount = [
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    },
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      disclosures: {
        employment_status: 'EMPLOYED',
        employer_name: '',
        employer_address: '',
        employment_position: '',
        is_control_person: false,
        is_affiliated_exchange_or_finra: false,
        is_politically_exposed: false,
        immediate_family_exposed: false,
        is_discretionary: false
      },
      agreements: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [ 'us_equity', 'crypto' ]
    }
  ]


const subAccounts = [
    [
     {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    },
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      disclosures: {
        employment_status: 'EMPLOYED',
        employer_name: '',
        employer_address: '',
        employment_position: '',
        is_control_person: false,
        is_affiliated_exchange_or_finra: false,
        is_politically_exposed: false,
        immediate_family_exposed: false,
        is_discretionary: false
      },
      agreements: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [ 'us_equity', 'crypto' ]
    }
    ],
    [
     {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      buying_power: '0',
      regt_buying_power: '0',
      daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      non_marginable_buying_power: '0',
      cash: '0',
      cash_withdrawable: '0',
      cash_transferable: '0',
      accrued_fees: '0',
      pending_transfer_out: '0',
      pending_transfer_in: '0',
      portfolio_value: '0',
      pattern_day_trader: false,
      trading_blocked: false,
      transfers_blocked: false,
      account_blocked: false,
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      trade_suspended_by_user: false,
      multiplier: '1',
      shorting_enabled: false,
      equity: '0',
      last_equity: '0',
      long_market_value: '0',
      short_market_value: '0',
      initial_margin: '0',
      maintenance_margin: '0',
      last_maintenance_margin: '0',
      sma: '0',
      daytrade_count: 0,
      previous_close: '2022-08-02T20:00:00-04:00',
      last_long_market_value: '0',
      last_short_market_value: '0',
      last_cash: '0',
      last_initial_margin: '0',
      last_regt_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrading_buying_power: '0',
      last_buying_power: '0',
      last_daytrade_count: 0,
      clearing_broker: 'VELOX'
    },
    {
      id: '0bc5c1f0-a083-45bd-929a-b426f237df5a',
      account_number: '794414973',
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      crypto_status: 'APPROVED',
      currency: 'USD',
      last_equity: '0',
      created_at: '2022-08-03T00:38:54.03764Z',
      disclosures: {
        employment_status: 'EMPLOYED',
        employer_name: '',
        employer_address: '',
        employment_position: '',
        is_control_person: false,
        is_affiliated_exchange_or_finra: false,
        is_politically_exposed: false,
        immediate_family_exposed: false,
        is_discretionary: false
      },
      agreements: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      account_type: 'custodial',
      custodial_account_type: 'UTMA',
      trading_configurations: null,
      enabled_assets: [ 'us_equity', 'crypto' ]
    }
    ]
]

console.log([...primaryAccount,...subAccounts.map(v => ({...v}))])
```

Comment: A step in the right direction! I noticed that you get '0': {...}, '1': {...} when I  run the code above. I need to figure out how to replace those to be 'accountInfo: {...}, 'tradingAccount: {...}